# Question about the definition of the degree of a continuous map $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

From Rotman's algebraic Topology:

> A continuous map $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ (where $n \gt 0$) has **degree** $m$, denoted by $d(f) = m$, if $f_*:H_n(S^n) \rightarrow H_n(S^n)$ is multiplication by $m$.

What does "is multiplication by $m$" mean for n-th homology groups?

Comment: Every abelian group $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, meaning that "scalar multiplication" by integers is defined by the formula $$na=\underbrace{a+...+a}_{\text{$n$ times (for positive $n$)}}$$ and satisfies a few basic laws such as $n(a+b)=na+nb$ and $n(mb)=(nm)b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$H_n(S^n)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ and so every homomorphism

$$f:H_n(S^n)\to H_n(S^n)$$

is actually a homomorphism

$$f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$$

and every such homomorphism is given by

$$f(x)=mx$$

for some unique $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.